# android ListView dynamic onitemclick

Tags: android, android-listview

I am creating a ListView dynamically inside of the adapter of a gridview. So what happens is, the gridview contains listviews in its cells. Inside of the gridview adapter, I create the listview with its own adapter. This works fine, however, I need to write a onitemclick listener for the listView to access the position of each of its items. Currently I am writing the onitemclick listener inside of the gridview adapter right after I have created the listview, however I am not sure how to gain access to the listview items.

Please help.

Here is the code where I create the listview, inside of the gridview adapter (getview method - I deleted the other irrelevant code):

```
 public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {
     ListView list;

        if (convertView == null)
        {  

              //if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes.  
              list = new ListView(mContext);
              list.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
              list.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 550));
              list.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
              list.setAdapter(new Adapter_ListView_GridView_Calendar(mContext, dagtyeVanhaarkappers.get(position-hairdresserids.size()), gebookdeurUser.get(position-hairdresserids.size()), tekening.get(position-hairdresserids.size())));
        }  
        else
        {
         list = (ListView) convertView;
        }  

        list.setCacheColorHint(0);
        list.setId(position-hairdresserids.size());

        list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
              {

                  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                  {   
                // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                      v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                      return false;
                  }
              });

       final int itemp = position;
       final int dayId = parent.getChildCount();

       list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
       {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
             {
               // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_make_booking);

                    //NOT SURE HOW TO ACCESS LIST ITEM POSITION FROM HERE ???

        dialog.show();
             }
       });

        return list;
     }
```

EDIT:

This is what I tried now but I keep getting a value of 0...

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
       {


             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
             {
               // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_make_booking);

                    //NOT SURE HOW TO ACCESS LIST ITEM POSITION FROM HERE ???

                    long l = list.getAdapter().getItemId(arg2); //THIS VALUE STAYS 0
                    String s = (String) String.valueOf(l);
        dialog.setTitle(s);

        dialog.show();
             }
       });
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped. The getitem was set to return 0 in the adapter of the list view ... sigh, but its working now. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the listview member of the current class and arg2 is the position of the listitem that was clicked.

Comment: I tried to access arg2 but the value stays 0 ? see EDIT above

Answer (score 1):

Is the itemp not recognized inside the onItemClick method?

Have you tried making the position variable final and access it?

Btw, int arg2 should be the position in itself

Comment: I tried to access arg2 but the value stays 0 ? see EDIT above